# SpringBootTest - how to assert context not loads and change properties at test level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I rely on `@SpringBootTest` heavily when testing application configuration.  App properties can be complex, having default values and non-trivial validations.  For example:

```
prop:
  ports: 1205,2303,4039
  fqdn: ${server.host}:${ports[0]}/${path}

@Configuration
SomeConfigClass{
   @Value{"${ports}:{#collections.emptyList}"}
   List<Integer> ports;

   ...
}
```

When testing such apps, I bring up a full or partial application context without mocks, as there is complexity in the context and validation itself - mocks don't capture this.  Unfortunately, there are two limitations I keep finding with this pattern:

1. How can we test that bad configurations *fail* to load?

   Imagine testing that the port in invalid because it is not on the restricted range of `500 - 1500`.

   ```
   @SpringBootTest(
           classes = {SomeConfigClass.class},
           properties = "port=9000"
   )
   public class BadConfigTest{

       @Test(expected = ApplicationContextFailedException.class)
       public void WHEN_port_9000_THEN_appcontext_fails_to_load() {}

   }
   ```

   Since the test framework loads *after* the application context, there appears to be no way to test that an app context fails to load. For now I actually write the tests, manually confirm they fail, and then annotation with `@Ignored` so they are not lost.
2. How to change properties at the test method, rather than class, level?

   `@SpringBootTest` is a class annotation, meaning application properties are bound at the test-class level.  This results in needing a test class for many sets of properties and bloats the test suite.  For example, I'll end up with test classes like:

   ```
   ConfigPropertiesAllValidTest
   ConfigPropertiesNoneSetTest
   ConfigPropertiesSomeValidSomeNotTest
   ```

   Where each of these only has one or two test cases.  Preferably, there'd be a single `ConfigPropertiesTest` class with different props for each test.  Is this possible?

Again - I want to avoid mocks as they don't capture the non-trivial context autoconfiguration performed by Spring at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We ended up using the `ApplicationContextRunner` described in this document:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-test-autoconfig

Comment: Adam - Thank you for your question (it is very well written) and your own answer to your question :) It helped me a lot. For people searching for information about `ApplicationContext` testing there is also article/guide about `ApplicationContextRunner` baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-runner and there are also `AssertableWebApplicationContext` and `AssertableReactiveWebApplicationContext` classes which might be helpful when testing web application context. It is also worth to mention that `ApplicationContextRunner`  is available since `2.0.0` version of `spring-boot-test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation along with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to load properties for different profiles. This is class level, so will only help for case 1 of your question.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SomeConfigClass.class})
@ActiveProfiles("badconfigtest")
public class BadConfigTest{
    ...
}
```

Then have an `application-badconfigtest.properties` with your bad config.

I don't think you'll find a way of changing properties between test methods in the same class. You can use @DirtiesContext to reload the application context, but I've not seen a way to use different property files. I guess you could inject the values into the config classes that have already loaded the properties.

Comment: Thanks - I have used the @ActiveProfiles annotation but it doesn't really make much difference because it still forces me to tie one set of properties to a test class